# Is it good to create a custom table for large post meta

Tags: php, serialization, wordpress

I have a meta box on `page` post type which contains a page builder. So, as a whole this can contain kind of a lengthy data. (text, urls...etc).

What I'm currently doing is, getting that whole data to a multidimensional associative array and store it in a single field of the `wp_postmeta` table. So, it'll be stored as a serialized string.

But, I'm in little doubt that, if somehow the page builder data can be too large to fit in a single column of `wp_postmeta` and it'll break the website.

So, I'm thinking of creating a custom table like `page_builder` and store all the data of the page builder metabox in that table.

So, is it possible ? Is it good practice ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the "page builder"? So users use this tool to create pages or webpages which are currently being stored in a single field in your database? Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried each method and then calculated page loading time at webpagetest.org? Whichever method results in less waiting time is the one you should use.

Comment: @JCutting8 yes, users can drag and drop elements like Textboxes, Image-boxes...etc and publish the page like a normal wordpress page.

Comment: @Mike No, I haven't tried the second method which I should create a custom table. What I've done already is just use default wp_postmeta. Page loading time is fine.

Comment: You need to try both methods and you need to measure the page load time down to the millisecond from each method.

Comment: Is the page load time, the only thing I have to concern here ?

Comment: I once used a method of storing files on the server (not in the database), and then using the database to link to the files. In my case, this was more useful because the files I was storing was photos, and I could then create URLs to the photos without querying the database. Just another approach you could consider.